# Finding duplicate values in 5 excel sheets and results to be moved in the sixt one

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find duplicated values from 5 different sheets, to color them and to move results in the sixth empty sheet + desribing from which sheet value has been taken.
I will give example:
I have 5 different direct marketing campaigns.The name of the sheet is the name of the campaign /Cam 1,  Camp 2..../. In each sheet I am storing customer ID data - /10 digit number/.In order not to dublicate the customers, during customer pre-selection process, I would like to screen duplicated IDs /from each sheet/ and to transfer them in separate empty sheet, together with info from which shees customer ID has been taken.
There are lot formula combinations, but I would like to do it through macros, because each campaigns is 200K and more IDs and using formula is very slowly and not each time succesfully.

I am expecting to find more easy solution for this task.

I will be very gratefull for your help.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I have used one VBA which only colors duplicated values in 3 sheets